# xp_regread SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use `xp_regread` on a new SQL Server 2012 server I have just installed.

Previously, I have used a query like the following on SQL Server 2008 servers to get the account running the current instance:

```
declare @regResult varchar(20)

exec master..xp_regread @rootKey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key = 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER',
    @value_name = 'ObjectName',
    @value = @regResult OUTPUT

select @regResult
```

However, I now get the following error when using the same query on SQL Server 2012:

> Msg 22001, Level 15, State 0, Line 0
>   Error executing Read extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter

I am assuming `xp_regread` has changed in SQL Server 2012. Does anyone know how it changed?

I am also open to a different query that doesn't use an extended stored procedure to get the service account running the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
select * from sys.dm_server_services
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204542.aspx

Comment: Is this confirming that the security issues from XP_Regread were mitigated in SQL Server 2012 onwards, if so can you point to documentation on this.